# Add Object in json file generate by services module drupal

Tags: services, 8

I need some help about this problem. I need to add object that encompasses the hash of my json file.

I use services module in drupal 6 for generate xml and json file from my nodes.
So, when i view my nodes in json i have this:

```
[
{
"nid": "7",
"vid": "7",
"type": "page",
"language": "",
"title": "Bievenido", ..... } ]
```

But i need that this json file look like this:

```
[
{
"<whatever>": {
    "nid": "7",
    "vid": "7",
    "type": "page",
    "language": "",
    "title": "Bievenido", .....  } ]
```

How to change this json file generated by services module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON is generated by the [`RESTServerViewBuiltIn` class](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21services%21servers%21rest_server%21includes%21rest_server.views.inc/class/RESTServerViewBuiltIn/7) in the `services/servers/rest_server/includes/rest_server.views.inc` file, specifically the `render_json` member function.

Services does provide a way to override this.

Firstly in a custom module implement [`hook_rest_server_response_formatters_alter`](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/services/servers--rest_server--rest_server.api.php/function/hook_rest_server_response_formatters_alter/6.3) and change the View class that's used to render the output to a custom one:

```
function MYMODULE_rest_server_response_formatters_alter(&$formatters) {
  $formatters['json']['view'] = 'RESTServerViewMYMODULE';
}
```

Then add your custom View class (I'd keep this in the module file to avoid having to load includes):

```
class RESTServerViewMYMODULE extends RESTServerView {
  public function render() {
    $new_data = new stdClass;
    $new_data->some_key = $this->model;

    $json = str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($new_data));

    return $json;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I don't understand the part of `$json = str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($data));` . In this part the own method convert to json file. How to override this conversion?... Do you have an example of this?

Comment: @Dvex: I've updated the answer to show you exactly how to wrap the existing data in a new object and serialise it JSON.