# Format of the JSON returned by the Services module

Tags: services

I have a big doubt about the JSON format the Services module (for Drupal 6) generates.

When I view the XML, all is OK.

```
<result is_array="true">
 <item>
  <nid>9</nid>
  <vid>9</vid>
  <type>producto</type>
 </item>
</result>
```

When I view the JSON, I see this:

```
[
 {
  "nid": "9",
  "vid": "9",
  "type": "producto",
 }
]
```

What I really is something like this:

```
[
 {
  "item":{
    "nid": "9",
    "vid": "9",
    "type": "producto",
  }
 }
]
```

How do I do this? Is there any configuration in the Services module that I can use to change the output, or do I need writing code?
I know the function to render JSON output.

Comment: Apologies I added the wrong link, this is the one you want: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20675/add-object-in-json-file-generate-by-services-module-drupal/20683#20683

Comment: thanks, but i don't understand... I obtain the json file from services module. But have a different structure that i need... I this example, i view that i create a new data and encode this. I need to override this existing json file that is generated.

Comment: You can use exactly the same method as in the linked answer, you override the abstract `render()` function in your class to change the JSON outputted by the module. You have access to the data object in `$this->model`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement `hook_services_request_postprocess_alter()`.

Comment: +1 can't believe I spent half an hour dissecting the RESTServer module to work out how to alter it's output directly when there's an overall hook. Doh :)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation of the hook, or example code showing how the hook should be written?

Comment: Another example of the abysmal Services docs. Will work on D8 WSCCI kill any chances for anyone to take on that task? Stay tuned... :-)

Comment: Work on D8 WSCII wil not kill services.

Comment: Tantalizing clues in services_log: http://drupalcode.org/project/services_log.git/blob/6da1590e35ff4a5851a730209bdc1de05209cdc8:/services_log.module This hook remains the only example Google can find. I really wish drupalcode.org were as easy to search as api.drupal.org.

Comment: With that hook, there is no way to know what type of data is it.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned before, [`hook_services_request_postprocess_alter()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!services!docs!services.alter.api.php/function/hook_services_request_postprocess_alter/7) won't provide you what type of data it's processing. It means that your code must be really hacky to catch exactly the type of data you need.

You better create your own formatter with [`hook_rest_server_response_formatters_alter()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!services!servers!rest_server!rest_server.api.php/function/hook_rest_server_response_formatters_alter/7) and use it to render data.